# What's the best data modeling strategy in React + Redux + Thunk + Axios application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, modeling

I have very extensive Java background, including both front end (Swing, JavaFX) and backend, and being relatively new at the Javascript side. Now I am involved in a large web application development using React, Redux, Thunk and Axios. I have done quite extensive research on React ecosystems and have a good understanding of all the moving parts, but I am still lost when dealing data modeling in React. Most of samples and documents are basically using javascript literal objects. And those objects are not that complicated. Most of applications I built have quite complicated data models, and those data models are all defined as Java Beans (Java classes), and they are reused everywhere possible.  But with React, Redux, Thunk and Axios, I can't seem to find a pre-defined data model, they seems to be coded on the spot. If the same object has to be reused in different components or pages, how can I reuse them?

Java Developer likes a strong typed object upfront, so I did quite some research on Flow, it seems that I could define a flow type upfront, and reuse the same Flow type when defining component State and Properties. Can I even use the same Flow type when using Axios? For example, axios response.data would be my pre-defined Flow type?

What's your data modeling strategy in React + Redux + Thunk + Axios application?

Thanks
Tao

Comment: Asking for opinions is off-topic on SO. Consider re-asking the question with specific coding problem as soon as you encounter it. *If the same object has to be reused in different components or pages, how can I reuse them?* It's unclear what you're asking about. Data class? React and Redux favour FP, you can deal with data as plain objects with purely functional approach. They can be typed as well. *For example, axios response.data would be my pre-defined Flow type?* Likely yes, why not? You may also benefit from Normlizr and other immutable data management libs (immer, redux-orm).

Comment: Hi estus, thanks for your answer. I have yet have a specific coding problem to ask. I am just considering the approaches to take when modeling a big React application. Where to define and reuse data models. I know javascript classes are different than java classes, in Java, everything is strong typed, even two classes have exact the same attributes but you can't exchange them for one another. I think I ask this question because I am still wearing my java developer's shoes.

Comment: I'd suggest to try Typescript first, it has better support from the community than Flow now. *even two classes have exact the same attributes but you can't exchange them for one another* - this is opposite in JS/TS. Types are applied structurally, this often confuses Java/C# folks. Check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html . This feature is common for Flow and TS.

Comment: Thanks estus. I think you nailed my pain point regarding the confusion. I am still trying to get over it. In Java, class is the 1st class citizen. Everywhere you pass a parameter, there will be a class. But in javascript, what I have been watching so far, there is no classes, almost just literal objects. For example, when Flow is not being used, a component State is just literal object. When receiving data from Axios using res.data, I don't even know what kind of object it is, there is no class information. It feels that javascript doesn't care about class, just care about object structure.

Comment: We tried typescript too, it feels there is a steep learning curve. Besides, the integration with ReactJS is not as easy as Flow. That's why we made the decision to use Flow.

Comment: React has no problems with TS if you want to jump into statically typed JS. TS is JSwith types and several non-compliant features that are optional. Flow and TS are on par, feature-wise. In my experience, React+TS setups are considerably more common than React+Flow now because TS has received a lot of attention. It's a good thing because type issues may be tricky to solve, and TS user base is much bigger. *It feels that javascript doesn't care about class, just care about object structure* - right, as I said. It's not JS but typing systems that don't care about classes, both Flow and TS.

Comment: Hi estus, your experience is very helpful for me. Could you point me some articles that are good for starters to integrate React and TS? I investigated based on quite a few online sources, I would say in terms of project configuration it's way more complicated and confusing for me that React + Flow.

Comment: As for configuration, it's no-config with CRA, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts-ts .  https://stackblitz.com/ and https://codesandbox.io/ already provide React+TS playgrounds powered by this package, you can download it as ready to use project if needed from there. I cannot recommend a guide to write React in TS, usually I just check React typings for proper types.

Comment: Btw, a link to the guide was posted in another topic, https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide